# Free indicator keyboard layout for Windows 10

Tags: keyboard-layout

### 1. Expected behavior

- I need program, show country flag or language capital letters — for example, `EN` for English keyboard layout, `RU` for Russian language and so on, — near carriage (not or not only mouse cursor).

**Example of expected behavior**: behavior of Aml Maple program.

[image: Aml Maple]

- Program must be free/open source.

---

---

### 2. Unsuitable

- [**Aml Maple**](http://www.amlpages.com/amlmaple.shtml), [**Curlyt**](http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=5&topic=39091), [**Comfort Typing**](http://ru.comfort-software.com/language-switcher.html) — commercial programs,
- [**Flean**](https://code.google.com/archive/p/flean/) — not worked in my Windows 10,
- [**LangCursor**](https://habrahabr.ru/post/138940/), [**Mouse Flying Indicator Tool**](http://www.deskex.com/Msatell/index.asp) — show language capital letters near cursor, not carriage. Also, both of programs have bugs for me.